# How to use CppCheck tool to review your c / cpp code in ubuntu?

Tags: static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I am trying to use the `CppCheck` tool in Ubuntu. I ran the following command

```
cppcheck --enable=all  --check-config --suppress=missingIncludeSystem main.c 2>err.txt
```

It is creating the `err.txt` file but it is empty.

How to get the ratings or check the code in the `main.c` file.

Comment: Share your main.c code, maybe err.txt is empty since there is no errors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

remove --check-config .. that tells cppcheck that you only want to check the command line configuration.